# Cannot mount rcloned drive because of FUSE error

Tags: ubuntu, fuse, rclone

I wanted to mount my rcloned drive. When I try to mount that rclone using this command:

```
rclone mount --allow-other Webseries: /webseries
```

I get the following error:

```
2022/04/28 21:59:46 mount helper error: fusermount: fuse device not found, try 'modprobe fuse' first
2022/04/28 21:59:46 Fatal error: failed to mount FUSE fs: fusermount: exit status 1
```

I want to mount it and referred to many thread related to this.

**What I tried**

- I tried

  ```
  whereis modprobe
  ```

  Output is :

  ```
  modprobe: /usr/lib/modprobe.d
  ```
- I have tried running

  ```
  modprobe fuse
  ```

  It responds with

  ```
  bash: modprobe: command not found
  ```

I feel like Fuse isn't installing.
I can't find any file related to fuse.

I installed fuse using

```
sudo apt-get install fuse
```

It successfully gets installed it .

**Kindly refer to the log.**
[Click here to see logs on pastebin!](https://pastebin.com/JWMNbzch)

**I'm running Ubuntu:20.04 on docker**.
And seems like docker doesn't like fuse very much.

I even tried using google-drive-ocamlfuse but The VNC rdp disconnects while opening browser for Google authentication.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135992/discussion-on-question-by-devansh-shrivastava-fusermount-fatal-error-failed-to).

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `fuse` module into the kernel (as root, outside Docker)

```
/sbin/modprobe fuse
```

Without this you won't be able to load the Fuse driver that `rclone` needs inside your Docker container.